# Cannot compile sass through compass after upgrading MAMP

Tags: compiler-errors, sass, compass-sass, codekit

I recently updated `MAMP` and now I am getting this error when I try to compile `sass` using the built in compass engine which has always worked before.

```
Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

Errno::ENOENT on line ["33"] of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/global_options_parser.rb: No such file or directory - /Applications/MAMP_OLD
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I was following this page here to do this.

http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/installation/updating-mamp

Which is why the `MAMP_OLD` in the error portion, I opened that file but I don't see what the issue is, it seems something went a little awry in codekit when I did the update? How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the framework I had set up, it needed to be re-added. All is well now